# Detect App Closing in React Native (Expo)

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, location, background-fetch

I have a React Native Mobile App on Expo that uses location both in background and foreground.
But I have a problem because when the app is closed (both on Android and iOS) it continues sending the user location to the server.

I need a way to detect when the App is closed (not backgrounded) to execute 2 actions:

1. Stop Location Updates
2. Mutate the userState to offline in the DB

In order to solve the problem I tried multiple solutions:

- React Native AppStates
- ComponentWillUnmount
- Unnoficial libraries like EventLifeCycle Listeners, etc.

Anyone can save me on this one? :)

Comment: Closed? Obviously terminated applications cannot send anything as they are not running.

Comment: @user18309290 I have a Background Task that sends the location in background and it continues running after the app is terminated. 

I'm using this: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/task-manager/